# Suzuki ATV LT160 wheel hub gets stuck going on

Tags: wheels, suzuki, atv

I've got a 2000 Suzuki LT160 ATV.  The bearings blew up inside the wheel hub while riding. I took the entire front right wheel assembly off, including the knuckle arm and cleaned everything. Had to buy new spacers, bearings, and dust seals. I re-used the wheel hub because 1) it's expensive and 2) it didn't look damaged.

I pushed the bearings into the hub using a hammer and an impact socket that fit just into the hub and on top of the bearing.

I cannot push the hub on and get it to sit flush with brake plate using just my hands. When I push the hub onto the steering knuckle until it gets stuck about 1/2 way down.

To get it off I have to use a gear puller.

The picture shows about how far I can get the hub on with just my hands. Notice the large amount of space between the bottom of the hub and the brake plate. There is a rubber gasket between the hub and the brake plate but it's not that big and wouldn't fill the space.

Is this normal?  Why would the hub get stuck like that?  Do I hammer the hub on?

I didn't have to use a gear puller to get it off when I did the brakes a couple years ago.  It was snug but just slid off.

[image: stuck wheel hub]

Links to the parts diagrams, had trouble getting the pictures into the post.

https://www.suzukipartshouse.com/oemparts/a/suz/50d0a274f870022c2c5344db/knuckle-arm

https://www.suzukipartshouse.com/oemparts/a/suz/50d0a274f870022c2c5344dc/front-wheel

https://www.suzukipartshouse.com/oemparts/a/suz/50d0a274f870022c2c5344dd/front-wheel-brake

Answer (score 0):

The spindle must have been deformed when they rode it back to the house, because I bought a new knuckle and the same bearings went on just fine.